# Error on Dead Outlets / Actions in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib

Is there a way to have Xcode refuse to build an app due to there being a dead outlet or action in my Xib, Nib or Storyboards ? I quite often build an app only to find it crashes due to a interface builder file is pointing to a key on my class which no longer exists.

I am slowly coming to the conclusion it is better to construct these pieces of UI programatically but I was wondering if there is a way at least for my older projects of Xcode warning me against these things ?

Comment: which version of Xcode do you use..?

Comment: It has nothing to do with building the app. of course  it might show a warning if its deluge hasn't been set or something. Maybe we can help you if you could brief on the error you are getting.

Comment: No its runtime issue. But say I have a class with an outlet called "label" with a UILabel hooked up tp it in IB. But then I rename that outlet in the code but forget to update IB. then my app would crash but I may not know why, I was wondering if there was a way of xcode telling me.

Comment: I just asked myself the same question and was wondering why this doesn't show up together with other IB warnings like *ambiguous content size* or *Unsupported Configuration*. Xcode even shows a little exclamation mark in the `Connections inspector`. Why not escalate that as a full warning?

Comment: Yeah, the compiler is smart enough that it could just do a basic traversal of the AST to work out the outlet is no longer connected properly. Maybe a good request for apple at developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it can't. The nature of Objective-C is dynamic so the connection between xib and code can not be sure in the compile/link stage.

You may implement

```
-(void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key{ NSLog(@"Key:%@", key);}
```

To find out what is missing. (Missing outlets will finally reach here.)