# Xcode stops in main.m with no error, no exception, no console output?

Tags: xcode, crash

Really confused what is going on. My app builds successfully, but when I try to run it, it crashes on a blank screen before any of my UI or view controllers can load.

- I have tested other Xcode projects, and they are working normally, so it is project specific.
- I have breakpoints activated for [all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode), but Xcode still stops in main.m.
- There are no errors and no new warnings in my code from when my project was last in a working state.
- I have tested creating a brand new storyboard with a blank UIViewController, and the problem still persists. Oddly enough, the simulator will run if I load into a blank UITabBarController with no view controllers.
- There are no [dead outlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655005/error-on-dead-outlets-actions-in-interface-builder) in any of my storyboards.

I made quite a few changes to my project (pro tip: always check that your app runs whenever you make a change and not just that it builds!), mostly centered around deleting unused files. I checked "Compile Sources" under "Build Phases" for my target, and everything looks good.

I've also checked out NSZombies, memory management, etc., but it doesn't seem to be a memory issue.

Please let me know what other details I can include!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I solved it!

I previously had custom fonts added to my application which I am no longer using. While I removed those font files from my project, I forgot to remove them from "Fonts provided by application" in my Info.plist file!